Android MTP - Windows explorer default file sorting
When an Android phone connected to Windows PC via USB "Transferring files" (MTP), explorer by default shows files sorted alphabetically.
How to set default sort by modified date?
Or better yet, is there a way make explorer to remember sorting for each folder?
Currently explorer remembers folder view/sort for each folder on local/network computer, but not for devices connected with MTP protocol.

Should work like any File Explorer. You should be able to just click on the column to sort the contents

It does, until I close the window or disconnect the phone. Then it reverts back to alphabetical order.

This was reported as working
